# How to execute a DAX Query from Microsoft Power Automate against Power BI REST API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, power-automate

I have a SSAS Tabular instance in a server, and I want to use Microsoft Power Automate to shoot an email notification to me when the data shows a specific trend.

How can I execute an `EVALUATE` DAX query from Power Automate against my SSAS Tabular instance, so it can return the aggregate table I need right into Power Automate?

I could not find a built-in connector that explicitly allows to execute this DAX Query. Is there any connector I can use for this? Like an OLE DB or OData? (I'm not a savvy on any of these two).

The goal is to execute the DAX Query to receive a small aggregated table from SSAS, which I will use to iterate through its rows and shoot an email notification if one of the fields is below a certain threshold.

---

**UPDATE11/18/2021:**

With the recent release of the [Dataset - Execute Queries | Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries) endpoint looks like this might be achieved.


I already leveraged this API from Postman but I'm struggling a bit to make it work in Power Automate, as the API authenticated with AAD and it's quite cumbersome to try the OAuth2 mechanism manually, so I wonder if this connector "[HTTP with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/webcontents/)" could help me authenticate myself against AAD and shoot the `executeQueries` call against Power BI REST API.


Any other ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: We decided to move to Azure Analysis Services but same issue remains. Any help appreciated! This might also become a MS Flow Idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use live connect and connect to Powerbi and create a table or matrix visual , you will be able to get the email notification based on the trend in the data.  Power Automate has connectors to Powerbi . Just give it a try .

Comment: I am not against using native Power BI notifications based on data trends. However, the requirement stated in the post goes way beyond that, as we want to leverage fully-tailored messages that include several points of data, both for internal and external recipients. Current workaround to this was implementing Azure Functions with direct connectivity into the Analysis Services cube, and run the DAX queries from there.